# Problems in Rails undefined method `map' for #<Contact:0x000000013aa76b48>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm putting together a combo box or called the same as a select in rails, I put everything together but it gives me an error that tells me that I have a problem with the map inside the select, I'm using simple_form_for and I'm doing a map inside the collection inside the selector or called in simple_for associatio.

I copy the view and the controller

This view

```
<h1>HistContact#index</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/hist_contact/index.html.erb</p> 
<%= simple_form_for @histcontact, url:hist_contact_index_path  do |f| %>
  <% f.association :contact, collection: @contacts.map{|cont| [cont.name , cont.id]}%>
  <%f.submit "buscar"%>
<% end %>
<table id = "client_table" class="table table-striped table-sm">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>fecha</th
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @histcontacts.each do |c|%>
      <tr>
        <td> <%= c.id %> </td>
        <td> <%= c.created_at %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

the controller

```
class HistContactController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @histcontacts = HistContact.all
    @contacts = Contact.all
  end

  def new
    @histcontact = HistContact.new
    @contacts = Contact.new 
  end

  def create
    @histcontact = HistContact.find(contact_id: params[:contact])
  end

  private

  def contactID(current_user)
    client_id = Client.where(user_id: current_user.id)
    contact_id = Contact.where(client_id: client_id.ids[0])   
    return contact_id
  end

end
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

According to error, you are trying to map a single object instead of an array of objects. Based on your controller code, the view file you shared is probably `new.html.erb`. To solve this problem you need do it like this:

```
def new
  @histcontact = HistContact.new
  @contacts = Contact.all
end
```